# I can't switch the database on Symfony 2.7

Tags: php, symfony

I am creating a Symfony 2.7 project and I would like to change the parameters.yml document.

My problem is that I worked in a local host with Xampp and, now, I need to link it to an online database. Sure, I first changed the name on parameters.yml as indicated in the photo.

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.
    database_port: null
    database_name: qvd913
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: secret_value_for_symfony_demo_application_ruben
```

The old name is `correolectronico` and the new name is `qvd913`. Symfony is not use this new value `qvd913`, take the old configuration. When I try the following:

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
```

I receive the following error:

> Could not create database `correoElectronico` for connection named default.
>
> An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `correoElectronico`':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'correoelectronico'; database exists

Comment: maybe Im missunderstanding.. but youve not changed the database_host value to the new 'online database'?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As a first step I changed the name of the database and I tried to create a new in local. How it didn't work, I didn't change the host. sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to clear your cache files
2. You need also to add those parameters in the parameters.yml.dist if you are deploying this app somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I use php app/console cache:clear --env=prod and put the values in   parameters.yml.dist but it don't work

Comment: THANKS A LOT ¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡¡ thanks and thanks and thanks.